# Как в App Designer связать два обратных вызова у кнопок, построить траекторию движения по координатам положения и ориентации?

Tags: matlab

В App Designer пытаюсь сделать приложение, которое построит траекторию по координатам: (x,y,z - позиция), (A,B,C - ориентация).
Создала три кнопки, которые должны:
1 кнопка: Ввести координаты - записать и сохранить значения координат в память приложения.
2 кнопка: Построить траекторию - построить саму траекторию.
3 кнопка: Сохранение - должна сохранить полученный результат, то есть 3d график.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    % Button pushed function: OKButton
    function OKButtonPushed(app, event)
    % Координаты положения 
    z = app.ZEditField.Value;
    y = app.YEditField.Value;
    x = app.XEditField.Value;
    az = app.AEditField.Value;
    yb = app.BEditField.Value;
    xc = app.CEditField.Value;

    % Сохранить введенные данные в память программы
    try 
        assignin('base', 'z', app.ZEditField.Value);
        assignin('base', 'y', app.YEditField.Value);
        assignin('base', 'x', app.XEditField.Value);
        assignin('base', 'az', app.AEditField.Value);
        assignin('base', 'yb', app.BEditField.Value);
        assignin('base', 'xc', app.CEditField.Value);
        msgbox('Точки сохранены в файле', 'Info');
    catch
        errordlg('Ошибка при сохранении файла', 'Info');
    end

    end

   
    % Button pushed function: Button
    function ButtonPushed(app, event)
     [FileName, PathName] = uiputfile('.jpg', 'Save');
     Name = fullfile(PathName, FileName);

    % [file,path] = uiputfile('.mat','Workspace File');
    end
```

Как осуществить (записать) код для второй кнопки я не знаю.

```
    % Button pushed function: OKButton_2
    function OKButton_2Pushed(app, event)
```

Как это можно осуществить (записать)?

Comment: "*Точки сохранены в файле*", а где сохранение в файл?